# Why doesn't the calc package work?

Tags: calculations

I'm trying to span two column in table (using `xtabular`) by the following command:

```
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*1)*2/2}|}
```

The package [`calc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) must calculate this equation:

```
\linewidth-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*1)*2/2
```

but I get a compile error:

> Missing number, treated as zero.

Even simple operation isn't calculated:

```
\arrayrulewidth*1
```

I use doxygen documentation and I create tables with HTML tags. 
This TeX table generated by doxygen:

```
\begin{TabularC}{2}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*1)*2/2}|}{Environment  }\\\cline{1-2}
Gravity acceleration &0.\-0  \\\cline{1-2}
Water depth &0.\-0  \\\cline{1-2}
Water density &0.\-0  \\\cline{1-2}
Wave frequencies &$<$empty$>$  \\\cline{1-2}
\end{TabularC}
```

And TabularC definition:

```
\newcommand{\PBS}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}%
\newlength{\tmplength}%
\newenvironment{TabularC}[1]%
{%
\setlength{\tmplength}%
     {\linewidth/(#1)-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*(#1+1)/(#1)}%
      \par\begin{xtabular*}{\linewidth}%
             {*{#1}{|>{\PBS\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{\the\tmplength}}|}%
}%
{\end{xtabular*}\par}%
```

Table in HTML:

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style='border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200)'>
<tr>
  <td colspan='2' style='background-color: black; color: white; text-align: center'>Environment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style='border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200)'>Gravity acceleration</td>
  <td>0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style='border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200)'>Water depth</td>
  <td>0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style='border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200)'>Water density</td>
  <td>0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style='border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200)'>Wave frequencies</td>
  <td>&lt;empty&gt;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Command `\multicolumn` generated from `colspan`.

Comment: I use doxygen, so that equation generetad by it. I post example with table.

Comment: Try `2\tabcolsep` instead of `\tabcolsep*2`

Comment: Tried `\linewidth-\tabcolsep` and still have this error.

Comment: Sorry, can't find anything useful. I don't understand, how TabularC is work, but using `\multicolumn` without equation `(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*1)*2/2` (for example, `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}`) working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let no one say *The LaTeX Companion* isn't useful!  Apparently `Doxygen` is cribbing from it (cf. p. 250).

This works, although the appearance of the table could certainly be improved:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{calc,xtab,array}

\newcommand{\PBS}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}%
\newlength{\tmplength}%

\newenvironment{TabularC}[1]{%
  \setlength{\tmplength}%
  {\linewidth/(#1)-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*(#1+1)/(#1)}%
  \par\begin{xtabular*}{\linewidth}%
    {*{#1}{|>{\PBS
          \raggedright\hspace{0pt}} p{\the\tmplength}}|}%
  }%
  {\end{xtabular*}\par}%

\begin{document}

\begin{TabularC}{2}
  \hline \multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*2-\arrayrulewidth*1)*2/2}|}%
  {Environment  }\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}

  Gravity acceleration &0.\-0  \tabularnewline\cline{1-2}

  Water depth &0.\-0  \tabularnewline\cline{1-2}

  Water density &0.\-0  \tabularnewline\cline{1-2}

  Wave frequencies &$<$empty$>$  \tabularnewline\cline{1-2}
\end{TabularC}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure what the exact problem was, maybe not loading the `array` package.  (This is often why a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) is so important.)

**Edit**  Output of `\listfiles` (put the command in the preamble, as [now] done above):

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
    xtab.sty    2011/07/31 v2.3f Extended supertabular package
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ***********
```

Comment: Sorry, that I can't give you more information. I'm new in TeX.
I can't compile this example, have the same error. Can it be problem with packages? May be too old version?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.20   {Environment  }
                      \tabularnewline\cline{1-2}
A number should have been here; I inserted '0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up 'weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Comment: And more info
l.20   {Environment  }
                      \tabularnewline\cline{1-2}
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Comment: @Anton -- Odd.  I added the output from `\listfiles`, but these are not packages that get modified too often, as you can see.  (Unfortunately, I must turn in now as I have an early morning tomorrow.  Hopefully some clarity will emerge between now than then!)

Comment: All right. I did update, and it work.

Comment: @Anton -- Great.  Glad it works now!